# Modificar el valor de una variable según dos atributos

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles

Estoy intentando automatizar un cambio en un fichero del siguiente formato:

```
 Valor  Atributo  zona
 1  world   0
 1  num 0
 1  basin   0
 100    ID  100
 0  sat 100
 1  lit.cover_fraction  100
 0  cover_fraction  100
 0  sat 100
 1  lit.cover_fraction  100
 0  cover_fraction  100
 120    ID  120
 0  sat 120
 1  lit.cover_fraction  120
 0  cover_fraction  120
 150    ID  150
 0  sat 150
 1  lit.cover_fraction  150
 0  cover_fraction  150
 0  sat 150
 1  lit.cover_fraction  150
 0  cover_fraction  150
 170    ID  170
 0  sat 170
 1  lit.cover_fraction  170
 0  cover_fraction  170
```

Estoy tratando de cambiar el valor del "cover_fraction" con los valores de una lista (New_cover), para cada ID. Pero también hay ID con 2 Stratum que deberían tener el mismo valor.

```
 ID = [100,120,150,170]
 New_cover = [30,50,20,40]
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
 Valor  Atributo  zona
 1  world   0
 1  num 0
 1  basin   0
 100    ID  100
 0  sat 100
 1  lit.cover_fraction  100
 30 cover_fraction  100
 0  sat 100
 1  lit.cover_fraction  100
 30 cover_fraction  100
 120    ID  120
 0  sat 120
 1  lit.cover_fraction  120
 50 cover_fraction  120
 150    ID  150
 0  sat 150
 1  lit.cover_fraction  150
 20 cover_fraction  150
 0  sat 150
 1  lit.cover_fraction  150
 20 cover_fraction  150
 170    ID  170
 0  sat 170
 1  lit.cover_fraction  170
 40 cover_fraction  170
```

Es decir, se modificarían las siguientes lineas:

-ID 100: (lineas 7 y 10) de 0 a 30 #Hay dos capas, debe repetir el valor

-ID 120: (linea 14) de 0 a 50

-ID 150: (lineas 18 y 21) de 0 a 20 #Hay dos capas, debe repetir el valor

-ID 170: (linea 25) de 0 a 40

Tengo el problema de que hay otra variable (lit.cover_fraction) muy similar a "cover_fraction" y no quiero que cambie el valor.

Me gustaría mucho una pequeña ayuda para guiarme a lograrlo.

Aquí dejo el código que estoy formulando por ahora:

```
 file = "C:/files.txt"
 salida = "C:/exit.txt"
 df= pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t")
 df1 = df.loc[df['Atributo'] == 'ID']

 ID = df1['Valor'].tolist()
 for i in range(0, len(ID)): 
     ID[i] = int(ID[i]) 
 #resultado: ID = [100,120,150,170]

 New_cover = [30,50,20,40] 

 for i,j in zip(ID,New_cover):
     for index, row in df.iterrows():            
             if (row[1] == 'cover_fraction' and row[2] == (i)):
                 print(row)
                 row[0]= str(j)

 final.to_csv(salida, header=True, sep='\t' )
```

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos!

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente la columna `zona` tiene el mismo valor para las filas pertenecientes a la misma `id`. Si esto es así la tarea se simplifica enormemente, puedes prescindir de complejos e ineficientes ciclos y tirar de Pandas directamente.

Puedes crear un diccionario con las ID como claves y el nuevo valor como valores y usar [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) para modificar las celdas correspondientes:

```
file = "C:/files.txt"
salida = "C:/exit.txt"

ID = [100, 120, 150, 170]
New_cover = [30, 50, 20, 40]
new_values = {id_: value for id_, value in zip(ID, New_cover)}

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')
select_rows = df["Atributo"] == "cover_fraction"
df.loc[select_rows, "Valor"] = df.loc[select_rows, "zona"].map(new_values)
df.to_csv(salida, header=True, sep='\t', index=False )
```

la salida es:

> ```
> Valor Atributo    zona
> 1 world   0
> 1 num 0
> 1 basin   0
> 100   ID  100
> 0 sat 100
> 1 lit.cover_fraction  100
> 30    cover_fraction  100
> 0 sat 100
> 1 lit.cover_fraction  100
> 30    cover_fraction  100
> 120   ID  120
> 0 sat 120
> 1 lit.cover_fraction  120
> 50    cover_fraction  120
> 150   ID  150
> 0 sat 150
> 1 lit.cover_fraction  150
> 20    cover_fraction  150
> 0 sat 150
> 1 lit.cover_fraction  150
> 20    cover_fraction  150
> 170   ID  170
> 0 sat 170
> 1 lit.cover_fraction  170
> 40    cover_fraction  170
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. He comprendido el código y me ha sido muy util.